# Pandas df converting timestamp column value format

Tags: python, macos, pandas, anaconda

I have a dataframe with the dates column listed in the following format `2017/08/23` and I would like to convert all values in the column to the following format:

```
2011-09-13
00:00:00
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime` from Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

date_string = StringIO("""date
2017/08/23
2017/08/24
2017/08/25""")

df = pd.read_csv(date_string)

pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Output:

```
0   2017-08-23
1   2017-08-24
2   2017-08-25
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: What if I would like to apply this to an entire column instead of creating a list of strings using `StringIO`?

Comment: Just do pd.to_datetime(df['date']).  That will do it on the entire column.

Comment: And what if the `date` column is actually the index?

Comment: df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)